# Input type 'date'

Tags: css, input

How can I customize input type 'date' for mobile? I want to have transparent background and text color white. I'm using this css now  `background:transparent;color:white;` but it's not working on mobile browser, just on desktop browser.. Any solution?

```
<div class="row padding-tab-row">
     <span class="text-design col-xs-6 text-left">Launch date</span>
     <input style="background:transparent;color:white;" 
            class="col-xs-6" type="date" name="date"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your code so we can test it

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin I've comed with an update

Answer (score 0):

Try this **CSS:**

```
input {
  opacity:    0; /* This makes your input field to be completely transparent */
  color:      #FFFFFF;
  background: #40A824; /* Replace this with your favorite */
}
```